# WKImage always return nil

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos, wkimage

Access assets image will always return nil, below is my code and assets catalog screen shot.

```
let image = WKImage(imageName: "sample")
print(image.image)
```

This will always prints nil.

[image]

Update: Updated screen shot

Comment: What are the image extensions (.jpg, etc)?

Comment: All are .png images.

Comment: can you click on red error dot that appear in right corner that you can get the error log what issue it is

Comment: It is not related to my question, please ignore that. I am able to run and when print it will return nil in log.

Comment: its related to your question just use the log of it bcz that the main error about your image. assets does stop your project run

Comment: @Nitin Gohel, please check my update.

Comment: check my answer that you are setting image set in wrong target's assest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115382/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-anand-suthar1987).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that from your screenshot you are setting the **Image Set** in `Assests.xcassets` in the `swiftWatch` **WatchOS** target and i think you are use that image for the `WKDemo` target so you get that nil.

Set that **Image Set** in your `WKDemo's` `Assests.xcassets` instead of WatchOS's `Assests.xcassets` then check.

That issue is your are setting **ImageSet** in different Target and your are try to load in Different Target.

**UPDATE**

After checking your sample project you are doing wrong code for getting image. Instead of `let image = WKImage(imageName: "sample")` you must be use `WKPickerItem()` object like following code:

```
 for i in 1...10 {
            let item = WKPickerItem()
            item.title = "Picker itme =\(i)"
            item.contentImage = WKImage(imageName: "sample")

            if let image = item.contentImage
            {
             print(image)
            }
            pickerItems.append(item)
        }
```

**OUTPUT IS**

[image]