# WKImage to Data always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, watchos, wkimage

I am trying to convert WKImage to Data(NSData) but always getting nil.

```
let image = WKImage(imageName: "sample")
print("Image = \(image)")

let imageData = image.imageData
print("Image Data = \(imageData)")
```

Below is out put

```
Image = <WKImage: 0x7a66ff40>
Image Data = nil
```

Comment: have a look here : https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkimage/1628152-imagedata

Comment: @DeyaEldeen Then how can one convert image to data(NSData) or this is not possible on watchOS ?

Comment: this might be useful, read it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984502/wkimage-always-return-nil

Comment: You can see in log I am getting image properly but when get it's imageData will return nil. I think it's not possible on watchOS

Comment: the last thing I can help with is, have a look at this code : https://github.com/mkoehnke/WKImageCache/blob/master/WKImageCache/WKImageCache.swift

Comment: @AnandSuthar The important part on DeyaEldeen comment is the discussion on it: `The value in this property is set using the init(imageData:) method. For image objects created using other methods, this property is nil`. So that's normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating `WKImage` with `init(imageName: String)` constructor, only `imageName` parameter will not be nil. `image` and `imageData` parameters are not nil only when `WKImage` was created via `init(image: UIImage)` or `init(imageData: Data)` respectfully.

You can get this `imageName`, then create `UIImage` with it's `init(named: String)` constructor, and then convert this `UIImage` to data using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` functions:

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: image.imageName!)!)
```

Comment: I can't use this method because I don't have the selected images names  from gallery